# Writing a Hilbert C*-submodule of $L^2(X)$ as an integral sum over Hilbert subundles

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

In Ergodic Theory, some (though not all) presentations of compact extensions use Hilbert bundles.
Given $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu,T)$ and a sub $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ one has an associated factor map $\pi:(X,\mu,T)\to (Y,\nu,T)$ (where $\pi(x)=\pi(x')$ iff ($x\in A\leftrightarrow x'\in A$) for every $A\in\mathcal{G}$) and a decomposition $\mu=\int\mu_yd\nu$ (where $\nu=\pi_*(\mu)$).

Then one can informally think of the space of functions in $L^2(X,\mu)$ as an "integral" over the spaces of functions $H_y:=L^2(X,\mu_y)$ for $\nu$-a.e. $y$. Moreover, the union $\coprod_yH_y$ defines a Hilbert bundle over $Y$ (of course, $Y$ a priori has no topological structure, so this is not strictly precise).
This is the approach taken in these [notes](https://matheuscmss.wordpress.com/2011/05/01/ert16-compact-extensions/) by Yuri Lima and in Ch. 9 of Glasner's book, for instance.

One then considers $L^\infty(Y)$-submodules (i.e. closed $L^\infty(Y,\nu)$-invariant subspaces) of $L^2(X,\mu)$. Now, here comes my problem. In proving many of the properties that one wants to prove for any such submodule $M$ (I won't go into these details or into compact extensions themselves) the authors usually consider the collection of $\{M_y\}_{y\in Y}$, which are thought of as closed subspaces of the $H_y$ defined above (i.e. $\{M_y\}_{y\in Y}$ is a subbundle of the Hilbert bundle). If $f\in M$, then $f_y$ is in $M_y$, where $f_y$ is just $f$ "seen" as an element of $L^2(X,\mu_y)$ instead of $L^2(X,\mu)$ (warning: this is not the conditional expectation $\mu_y(f))$. For instance, if we fix topological models such that $X=Y\times U$ then $f_y=f(y,\cdot)$ The problem is that $f$ is not a function, it is an equivalence class of functions. Certainly, for a fixed $f\in L^2(Y\times U)$ the function $f_y=f(y,\cdot)$ is defined for $\nu$-a.e. $y$. But that doesn't mean we can actually define a map $M\mapsto \{M_y\}_{\nu\text{-a.e.} y}$ for any closed subspace $M$, since such subspaces have uncountably many $f$'s.

Question: Is there a way around this technical problem?

Comment: Perhaps you know that in the definition of conditionals along weak stable and weak unstable foliations we have a similar problem: there is no canonical transversal. Still, absolute continuity allows one to overcome the "problem" for example to study ergodic properties, since the holonomies have the absolute continuity property, independently of the transversal.